# How to add an IFrameElement inside a Widget in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, iframe

Is there a way to add an IFrameElement inside a Widget? I Have a PopUp with a FlowPanel that I would like to put an IFrame in there.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Frame` widget provided by GWT. GWT wraps `IFrameElement` in `Frame` widget. You can use it like any other widget. Further you can do all the manipulation for `IFrameElement` in Frame widget. For example

```
FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();
Frame frame = new Frame("http://www.google.com/");
fp.add(frame);
```

You can know more about Frame wrapper here : http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Frame.html